# sed replace all zeros with ones and all ones with zero

Tags: sed

have this:
`0|1    1|1    0|0    1|0    .|1    0|.`

want this:
`1|0    0|0    1|1    0|1    .|0    1|.`

I was thinking this would work:
`sed -e 's/0/1/g' -e 's/1/0/g'`

but just seems to give me all zeros

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427940/main-difference-between-tr-translate-to-sed-and-awk/427944#427944

Comment: It ends up with all zeros because you first replace all the zeros with ones (giving you a string of all ones) and then replace all those ones with zeros. A solution is to replace all the ones with twos, then replace all the zeros with ones, and then replace all the twos with zeros.

Comment: @KenWhite Great minds think alike! Funny we both picked 2

Comment: @MikeSlinn: That is funny. :-) You did a good job of answering, too. Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's play computer.

Given this:

`0|1    1|1    0|0    1|0    .|1    0|.`

... change all 0s to 1s. Now you have this:

`1|1    1|1    1|1    1|1    .|1    1|.`

... OK, now you are stuck. There are only 1s left and you do not know which to change back.

... so instead change the 0s into 2s, just for a brief moment:

`2|1    1|1    2|2    1|2    .|1    2|.`

... now change the 1s to 0s

`2|0    0|0    2|2    0|2    .|1    2|.`

... and then the 2s to 1s

`1|0    0|0    1|1    0|1    .|1    1|.`

And now the grand finale:

```
$ sed -e 's/0/2/g' -e 's/1/0/g' -e 's/2/1/g'
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down-voted -- it does a good job of explaining the problem and offers a decent solution.  Have an up-vote.

Answer (score 6):

There is a slightly lesser-known sed [command to transliterate, `y`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-y-_0028transliterate_0029-command), which comes in handy here:

```
$ sed 'y/01/10/' <<< '0|1    1|1    0|0    1|0    .|1    0|.'
1|0    0|0    1|1    0|1    .|0    1|.
```

Comment: This solution is the one to use. This does exactly what the question asks for in a robust and reliable manner rather than relying on a hacky temp substitution.